# Equality in Axler 6.A.12

Tags: solution-verification, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Axler exercise 6.A.12 states:

> Prove that
> $$(x_1 + \ldots + x_n)^2 \leq n (x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2)$$
> for all positive integers $n$ and all real numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_n$.

I have no problem proving this using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to $(1, \ldots, 1)$ and $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. My question is about when equality holds. Particularly, I am looking for a condition for which equality holds if and only if that condition is satisfied.

I'm able to prove that if these two vectors are linearly dependent, then equality holds. I'm having trouble proving that if equality holds, these two vectors are linearly dependent. If equality holds, I have:
$$(x_1 + \ldots + x_n)^2 = n (x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2).$$
The only thing I can do is take square roots:
$$|x_1 + \ldots + x_n| = \sqrt{n} \sqrt{x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2}.$$
If I had equality, then $(1, \ldots, 1)  = t (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ so $tx_i = 1$ for all $i$ and every entry of the $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ would have to be the same. I don't know how to derive that from the above conditions.

Is it possible that this implication is not double-sided? Otherwise, how can I prove that equality implies this condition?

Comment: Hint: go back to the proof of Cauchy-Schwartz.

Comment: @SubhajitGhosh I tried to do that, though I didn't make any progress.

Comment: If you look at [this pdf](https://rgmia.org/papers/v12e/Cauchy-Schwarzinequality.pdf), study **proof 2**.  The only way that equality can occur is if there is a specific value of $x$ such that $(a_i x - b_i)^2 = 0$, for each term $i$.  The only way that this can occur is if for all $i$, the ratio $\frac{b_i}{a_i}$ is constant.

Comment: Look up Rearrangement Inequality for what I think is the most intuitive reasoning for this inequality.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If you look at the proof of [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality?wprov=sfti1) inequality proof, you’ll see that equality holds if and only if the two vectors are linearly dependent.

Hence, in this case the equality holds if and only if it exists $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ such that
$$x_1=\cdots =x_n=\lambda.$$

Comment: I think part of my confusion is convincing myself that equality of Cauchy-Schwarz is enough because the quantity $(1, \ldots, 1) \cdot (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ may be negative.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't matter as you square it.

Comment: But I'm trying to work backwards from the equality holding at the level of squares. How do I back out $x_i = \lambda$ for all $i$ from that?

Comment: Man... what does it mean for $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ and $(1, \dots, 1)$ to be linearly dependent?